# Use variables instead of values in sed commande to replace words in a text file

Tags: variables, awk, sed, replace, fstab

I have to edit /etc/fstab to change mounting options for /dev/shm parameter.

source line is :

```
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   size=11g        0 0
```

I want to add noexec to the fourth field (mounting options) for the /dev/shm partition for many of servers.(with different size in mounting options)
So I tiried this code:
To obtain the value of mounting options. I used:

```
shmvar=`grep -E '\s/dev/shm\s' /etc/fstab | awk '{ print $4 }'`
```

the output is : `size=11g`

```
sed -i -e '/shm/s/$shmvar/$shmvar,noexec/' /etc/fstab
```

OR

```
sed -i -e '/shm/s/$shmvar/&,noexec/' /etc/fstab
```

but none of the sed commands worked.

while I use "size=11g" instead of "$shmvar" it works:

```
 sed -i -e '/shm/s/size=11g/size=11g,noexec/' /etc/fstab
OR
sed -i -e '/shm/s/size=11g/&,noexec/' /etc/fstab
```

But because the "size" value is different in servers, I have to use variables

Would highly appreciate some quick help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With **GNU** `awk`. If second field contains `/dev/shm` then append `,noexec` to fourth field.

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN{ OFS="\t" } $2=="/dev/shm"{ $4=$4 ",noexec" } { print }' file
```

Output:

```
tmpfs   /dev/shm        tmpfs   size=11g,noexec 0       0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , it works
Is there any way to change directly the fstab file ?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Assuming the input file is tab-separated since you're making it tab-separated in the output, you should probably change `OFS="\t"` to `FS=OFS="\t"` so it won't fail if any of the fields are empty or contain blanks, e.g. maybe `/dev/shm` could be `/dev/foo bar`, idk.